# How to pass some vars from module to template file

Tags: drupal

I've created custom block using API, now I want to pass my vars to the template (block-block-1.tpl.php). How can I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Define your arguments in [hook_theme](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) (make sure to select the the correct version there, 6 or 7 depending on what you are using). Then just call [theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme/7) and pass the arguments to it. Note that again, Drupal 6 (multiple arguments) and Drupal 7 (one argument with a assoc array) are different.